# L'article partitif dans des phrases négatives

Tags: grammaire, articles, négation, partitif

Ce qui suit est issu de la page 20 de *Schaum's Outline of French Grammar* de Mary Crocker :

> Normally, in negative sentences, the partitive article is replaced by **de**... Note
>   that de becomes d’ before a word beginning with a vowel.
>   If the sentence implies an affirmative idea or if you want to emphasize the noun, you may use the partitive article in negative sentences :
>
> Je n’ai pas du respect pour lui, mais du mépris.

Je suis décontenancé. On peut exactement enfreindre cette règle de grammaire ?

[De la page 73 de *Vautrin: drame en cinq actes et en prose* par Honoré de Balzac :](http://books.google.com/books?id=xeE-AAAAYAAJ&pg=RA1-PA74&dq=%22pas+du+pudeur%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=8OXlUsjMLbC8iAf36IDYBA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22pas%20du%20pudeur%22&f=false)

> Ma mére, la mienne est-elle donc hors de propos? Un jeune homme arrive, froisse des sentiments, se mêle, lui inconnu, aux plus grands noms, on lui fait place, il accepte comme si tout lui était dû! et je n’aurais pas le droit de rechercher si son assurance n’est pas de **l’** effronterie, ni de m’enquérir auprés de madame, par exemple, si les Frescas d’Aragon ne sont pas éteints?

[De la page 386 de *Livre des orateurs*](http://books.google.com/books?id=-7QPAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA386&dq=%22pas+de+l%27insolence%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=ZOzlUtOnIKqsiAfg3IHABw&ved=0CEkQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22pas%20de%20l%27insolence%22&f=false) par Louis-Marie de Lahaye de Cormenin :

> Et les doctrinaires, son rôle fini, lui ont tourné le dos et l'ont laissé là! ils haussaient légèrement les épaules, en passant au pied de la tribune, lorsqu'il y battait de la grosse caisse, et pour plus de pitié, ils ne l'honoraient même pas de **l'** insolence de leurs murmures.

Comment: Je pense que, dans le premier exemple, on aurait tout intérêt à remplacer « mépris » par « admiration » pour qu’il aie un peu de sens. Et même dans ce cas, je n’exprimerai pas cet idée comme ça.

Comment: Dans les phrases de Balzac et Cornerin, les « de » ne sont pas des partitifs, mais des prépositions.

Comment: Le downvote c'est parce que tu ne fais aucun effort pour recopier les citations proprement (si tu veux de l'aide c'est la moindre des choses, et ce n'est pas la première fois que je fais la remarque).

Comment: @Édouard: Dans Balzac c'est bien un article partitif (en effet dans Cormenin c'est une préposition), mais dans le cas du verbe *être* la règle énoncée ne s'applique pas. Je soupçonne l'OP d'avoir élidé une partie importante du contexte dans lequel elle a été énoncée.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Effectivement, j’ai lu le Balzac un peu vite.

Answer (score 2):

Je fais une réponse un peu au feeling, qui sera sans doute complétée ou corrigée par des références grammaticales sérieuses.

*Je n’ai pas du respect pour lui, mais du mépris*, ça ne sonne pas très joli, je dirais que *Je n’ai pas **de** respect pour lui, mais du mépris* est plus agréable à l'oreille. Et le sens s'y retrouve aussi. Comme le dit le manuel de grammaire, la différence est dans l'emphase posé sur le mot lui-même. On pourrait traduire ainsi la différence :

- *Je n’ai pas de respect pour lui, mais du mépris* - I have no respect for him, but contempt
- *Je n’ai pas du respect pour lui, mais du mépris* - What I have for him is not respect, but contempt.

Le première phrase parle plus de ce que je ressens pour lui, la seconde se concentre plus sur l'opposition entre respect et mépris. Dans une conversation, cela donnerait ceci :

1/ - Bien qu'il soit un homme politique en vue, je n'ai pas de respect pour lui, mais du mépris.

2/ - Je sais, le respect est une attitude noble, cependant je n'ai pas du respect pour lui, mais du mépris.

Le problème, c'est que pour que cette deuxième formulation passe (pour qu'elle sonne juste à l'oreille du locuteur), il faut qu'elle doit prononcée avec l'emphase correcte; sinon cela va sonner agrammatical :

*Je n'ai pas ... du *respect* ... pour lui, mais du mépris*. Bref, il faut vraiment poser l'emphase sur le mot mépris.

Mais, entre nous, la différence de sens est assez légère. Si tu oublies cette exception, tu survivras très bien. Je préfère nettement dire et écrire *je n'ai pas de respect pour lui, mais du mépris.* qui sonne toujours bien à l'oreille, et faire confiance au contexte pour que l'allocutaire ou le lecteur comprenne que l'emphase se porte sur mon sentiment ou sur les notions de respect et de mépris.

Answer (score 2):

Les règles de grammaire ne sont pas des lois que l'on peut enfreindre ou que l'on doit respecter et la langue appartient au peuple  qui la fait vivre, la parle, l'écrit, la transforme...

Ceci dit dans la phrase en question :

> Je n’ai pas du respect pour lui, mais du mépris.

L'emploi de **du** est tout à fait justifié ici et voulu par l'auteur pour marquer  l'opposition entre les deux sentiments. L'explication donnée par la grammaire que tu cites est bonne.